# Redux dispatch on requestAnimationFrame taking 250-300ms

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this is the case, but one of the simplest actions in my React app is being dispatched on each animation frame like so:

```
  step = () => {
    if (this.player.howler.playing()) {
      this.props.playProgress(this.player.seek())
      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.step)
    }
  }
```

playProgress is an absurdly simple action, but is taking a ludicrous amount of time to execute:

```
/**
 * Dispatched when currentlyPlaying's position changes
 *
 * @param  {integer} pos Position to progress to (in seconds)
 *
 * @return {object} An action object with a type of PLAY_PROGRESS
 */
export function playProgress(pos) {
  return {
    type: PLAY_PROGRESS,
    pos,
  }
}
```

And it's reduced like so:

```
case PLAY_PROGRESS:
  return state
    .setIn(['currentlyPlaying', 'pos'], action.pos)
```

Why on earth would that take so long to execute?? `window.requestAnimationFrame` only gives you 16ms before it executes again, so 250ms isn't cutting it... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post some codes about calculating the time?

Comment: @huachengzan Chrome Dev Tools is showing 100-150ms, and the frames go from 50-60 fps to a couple per second when the player comes on. What would you like to see exactly? Here's a screenshot: https://ibb.co/jNSShk Around 14000ms is where the player is turned on and the action starts executing.

Comment: Have you tried debouncing your calls to `playProgress` - seems like you may be calling it too often. Remember that every time you update state, every container will re-map store to props, and then re-render if different.

Comment: @AndrewBreen this is for a waveform progress, so it honestly needs to execute as fast as possible :/

Comment: @trevorhinesley the first step would still be to debounce the call to the time it's taking to execute to make sure you aren't adding additional processing and slowing down the queue of calls. Then you can investigate where that part of the state is used - it sounds like your problem is across the full cycle (dispatch => action => reducer => connect) - you can't do much more about the action or the reducer, so you need to fix how you dispatch and how the connected components work.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without more code. You need to have more detailed debug output. Maybe `this.player.seek()` takes forever, not `playProgress`

Comment: @dube this question is from 2 years ago, but I believe this wound up being related to an issue in Chrome related to infinite scrolling. It was extremely hard to debug, but we found it. Here's a breakdown: https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/pull/125

Comment: @TimPietrusky finally we did! See my comment to dube.

Comment: Yeah well, I sorted by unanswered... maybe close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but I believe it was related to an infinite scrolling issue we encountered in Chrome. Here's a rundown: github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/pull/125